# how to add apikey to API using swagger yaml with python-flask (creating own API)

Tags: python, api, flask, swagger

I am using swagger yaml and python Flask to create API. And I got stucked in create the API_key feature to the API.

I found an example from swagger documentation: https://github.com/zalando/connexion/tree/master/examples/openapi3/apikey, but when I run the example itself, it shows me that it is unauthorized (because no token was given) and therefore returns 401 error.

[image]

My question is that: why doesn’t it even go through the function in the example? Is there some bug in the current swagger yaml, how should I fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, the example works for me. Are you running the example as is? Describe the things you're doing that result in this error.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I found out actually it is not working because of my computer setting (there is some VPN or security settings that prevent it from working). I tried the same code in another computer and it works!